# How to parse a json response in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i am having a json response like this:

```
{
    "status":"ok",
    "dfs":[{"type":"i",
    "title":"image",
    "image_path":"https:\/\/s3.dhgdfhgfhgdhgfh\/ad_226.png"}]
}
```

and I am parsing like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict=[[request responseString] JSONValue];                
NSLog(@"dict %@ ",[request responseString]);

if([[dict objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ok"])
{                   
    NSMutableDictionary *dict1=[dict objectForKey:@"dfs"]; 

    NSLog(@"%@",[dict1 classForCoder]);
    NSLog(@"%@dict1",dict1);
    titlelbl.text=[dict1 objectForKey:@"title"];

    if ([[dict1 objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"i"])
    {
        ad.hidden=NO;

        NSString *imageurl=[dict1 objectForKey:@"image_path"];

        NSLog(@"%@",imageurl);
    }
```

But I get this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde7ecf0' .

I got the `dict1` class folder as `nsmutable` array. Can anybody help me in how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
"status":"ok",
"dfs":
[
{
"type":"i",
"title":"image ",
"image_path":"https:\/\/s3.dhgdfhgfhgdhgfh\/ad_226.png"
}
]
}
```

read the json response as above, its a dictionary, within it first object is string, second is an array of dictionary (which has only one object).

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[request responseString] JSONValue];

if([[dict objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ok"])
{
     NSArray* arr = [dict objectForKey:@"dfs"];
     NSDictionary* dict1 = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
enter code here
enter code here
enter code here
enter code here

// get the data from dict1 with the key value pairs, and set labels and images
}
```

Comment: titlelbl.text=[dict1 objectForKey:@"title"];after this will work?